# Enforce Entity Framework to follow constraints defined in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, constraints

I have a table with 10 columns, in which 7 of them are not null with constraints on it.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] 
    ADD DEFAULT (1) FOR [Column1]
```

Now, when I am inserting 3 columns from Entity Framework like below, it is not inserting the default values into the table:

```
Table obj1 = new Table();
obj1.Column7 = someValue;
obj1.column8 = someValue;
obj1.column9 = someValue;
context.Entry(obj1).State = EntityState.Added;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Unlike my expectation, above statement is just updating 3 columns and not using the default values for the other 7 columns.

How can I enforce Entity Framework to insert default values defined by the constraint in database?

Comment: Change the `Table` class to set the `Column1` property to the default value in it's constructor.

Comment: Also I think instead of `obj1= new Table()` you can do `obj1 = context.Tables.Create()`, that might solve the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default values as defined in your SQL Server table structure are **only applied** if you have an `INSERT` statement that **leaves out** those columns - e.g. doesn't provide any value (including `NULL`) for those columns.

EF however will always supply values for **all** columns as defined by the entity - e.g. it will supply `NULL` for any values not explicitly set. There's nothing you can do about this, as far as I know.

There are some workarounds:

- you could create a **stored procedure** which would take only those values you want to supply, and would run a SQL `INSERT` statement that would *leave out* the columns with default values, e.g.

  ```
  INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (colA, colB, ..., colZ)  -- *exclude* "Column1" here!
  VALUES ( .........)
  ```

  With this, SQL Server would then use the configured **default values** for those column that have one defined and which are not mentioned in the column list of the `INSERT INTO` statement
- you could probably do something similar on the EF level, by specifying a second class, that would be almost identical to your current entity class - but that would **leave out** the columns you want to have set by SQL Server's configured default values. If you save this "slimmed down" entity, EF would create a SQL statement that would include *only those columns* that it knows about (in terms of the fields of that slimmed down class) and this would result basically in the same as above - an `INSERT INTO` statement that **excludes** those columns which are automatically set by a configured SQL Server default constraint

Comment: Thanks for providing alternates, though I have resolved it using default value in property itself  public int Column7 { get; set; } = 1; as I was using .NET 6. Though, I don't think adding default at both code and database is a good idea. 

Thanks again for the answer. I will use stored procedure more frequently now for those cases.